# Postfix is Sending Spam

Tags: email, cpu-usage, smtp, spam-prevention, postfix

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 server, hosted on AWS, that powers a dozen WordPress installations using Nginx and php5-fpm.

The problem just began one day. My server was down. Panic! Whenever I turned it on again, after a few minutes it always died again. Postfix was taking 100% of CPU until the server ran out of breath. I was shocked to find out something is sending emails at an inhumane rate.

This is my postfix configuration (`/etc/postfix/main.cf`):

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = ip-172-31-3-94.eu-west-1.compute.internal alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases myorigin = /etc/mailname mydestination = creatroopers.com., ip-172-31-3-94.eu-west-1.compute.internal, localhost.eu-west-1.compute.internal, localhost relayhost = mynetworks
= 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 mailbox_size_limit = 0 recipient_delimiter = + inet_interfaces = all
```

Here's a **one second** worth of logs from `/var/log/mail.log` (creatroopers.com is my server):

```
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/cleanup[14534]: 0092B47C77: message-id=    <20140317111547.0092B47C77@ip-172-31-3-94.eu-west-1.compute.internal>
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/qmgr[12501]: 0092B47C77: from=<www-data@creatroopers.com>, size=636, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/smtp[12531]: connect to mailin-02.mx.aol.com[64.12.88.164]:25: Connection timed out
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/smtp[12534]: connect to mx.hover.com.cust.hostedemail.com[216.40.42.4]:25: Connection timed out
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/smtp[12535]: connect to usamail.com[209.15.13.134]:25: Connection timed out
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/smtp[12534]: A9E6947A48: to=<fredaklanro@grammail.com>, relay=none, delay=151, delays=121/0.51/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mx.hover.com.cust.hostedemail.com[216.40.42.4]:25: Connection timed out)
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/smtp[12535]: F223B47A8D: to=<frbbbjx@usamail.com>, relay=none, delay=149, delays=119/0.55/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to usamail.com[209.15.13.134]:25: Connection timed out)
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/smtp[12545]: connect to sakha.net[146.185.211.229]:25: Connection timed out
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/smtp[12545]: D4CDE47A63: to=<fred2@sakha.net>, relay=none, delay=148, delays=118/0.6/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to sakha.net[146.185.211.229]:25: Connection timed out)
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/smtp[12543]: connect to smtp-in.sto-hy.se.stejtech.net[79.136.102.100]:25: Connection timed out
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/pickup[12500]: 4862B48363: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/cleanup[15130]: 4862B48363: message-id=<20140317111547.4862B48363@ip-172-31-3-94.eu-west-1.compute.internal>
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/smtp[12544]: connect to mxs.mail.ru[94.100.180.150]:25: Connection timed out
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/smtp[12533]: connect to ebmail.com[72.52.4.90]:25: Connection timed out
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/smtp[12546]: connect to searchmail.com[72.52.4.90]:25: Connection timed out
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/qmgr[12501]: 4862B48363: from=<www-data@creatroopers.com>, size=636, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/pickup[12500]: 5CAC44829F: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/cleanup[14534]: 5CAC44829F: message-id=OrJkZNj-UTgCbNO-oX@creatopix.com
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/smtp[12546]: 2F1FD47A5F: to=<fredamacclip@searchmail.com>, relay=none, delay=150, delays=119/0.63/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to searchmail.com[72.52.4.90]:25: Connection timed out)
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/smtp[12533]: B5E6747AE6: to=<fredadketa@ebmail.com>, relay=none, delay=153, delays=122/0.5/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to ebmail.com[72.52.4.90]:25: Connection timed out)
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/pickup[12500]: 5FDC647D02: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/cleanup[15130]: 5FDC647D02: message-id=<20140317111547.5FDC647D02@ip-172-31-3-94.eu-west-1.compute.internal>
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/qmgr[12501]: 5FDC647D02: from=<www-data@creatroopers.com>, size=636, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/qmgr[12501]: 5CAC44829F: from=<www-data@creatroopers.com>, size=2108, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/smtp[12548]: connect to mx01.gmx.com[74.208.5.27]:25: Connection timed out
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/smtp[12547]: connect to mxs.mail.ru[94.100.180.150]:25: Connection timed out
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/smtp[12549]: connect to relay.verizon.net[206.46.232.11]:25: Connection timed out
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/smtp[12561]: connect to mxs.mail.ru[94.100.180.150]:25: Connection timed out
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/smtp[12549]: 8F26947A53: to=<frederikahallam9933@verizon.net>, relay=none, delay=149, delays=118/0.79/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to relay.verizon.net[206.46.232.11]:25: Connection timed out)
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/smtp[12534]: connect to ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM[2a00:1450:400c:c05::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/pickup[12500]: 8206C4811D: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/cleanup[14534]: 8206C4811D: message-id=<20140317111547.8206C4811D@ip-172-31-3-94.eu-west-1.compute.internal>
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/qmgr[12501]: 8206C4811D: from=<www-data@creatroopers.com>, size=636, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/pickup[12500]: 8BAFB47E02: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/cleanup[15130]: 8BAFB47E02: message-id=<20140317111547.8BAFB47E02@ip-172-31-3-94.eu-west-1.compute.internal>
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/pickup[12500]: 8E05B48185: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/cleanup[14534]: 8E05B48185: message-id=<20140317111547.8E05B48185@ip-172-31-3-94.eu-west-1.compute.internal>
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/qmgr[12501]: 8E05B48185: from=<www-data@creatroopers.com>, size=636, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/qmgr[12501]: 8BAFB47E02: from=<www-data@creatroopers.com>, size=636, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 17 11:15:47 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/pickup[12500]: 905C1480E6: uid=33 from=<www-data>
```

See? It's horrible. If I reinitialize the server and run `service postfix stop`, in the log I get `Mar 18 09:49:10 ip-172-31-3-94 postfix/master[25358]: terminating on signal 15` and the server becomes healthy again. But somehow every morning at 8:55 postfix wakes up on its own and shuts down the server again.

I see that the user that initiated all of these operations is "www-data" so running `ps auxww|grep ^www-data` gives us:

```
www-data   870  0.0  0.1  78208  3356 ?        S    09:41   0:02 nginx: worker process
www-data   871  0.0  0.1  78208  3356 ?        S    09:41   0:03 nginx: worker process
www-data   872  0.0  0.1  78208  3356 ?        S    09:41   0:02 nginx: worker process
www-data   875  0.0  0.1  78208  3356 ?        S    09:41   0:02 nginx: worker process
www-data  8066  0.2  0.0  25096  1464 ?        S    16:10   0:00 /usr/sbin/sendmail -i -FCronDaemon -oem www-data
www-data  8343  1.0  0.0  25088  1408 ?        D    16:10   0:00 /usr/sbin/postdrop -r
www-data  8380  1.2  0.0  25096  1464 ?        R    16:10   0:00 /usr/sbin/sendmail -i -FCronDaemon -oem www-data
www-data  8616  0.0  0.2 263332  4924 ?        S    16:10   0:00 php-fpm: pool www                                                       
www-data  8617  0.0  0.0  25096  1464 ?        S    16:10   0:00 /usr/sbin/sendmail -i -FCronDaemon -oem www-data
www-data  8638  0.0  0.0  25096  1464 ?        S    16:10   0:00 /usr/sbin/sendmail -i -FCronDaemon -oem www-data
www-data  8640  0.0  0.0  25096  1464 ?        S    16:10   0:00 /usr/sbin/sendmail -i -FCronDaemon -oem www-data
www-data  8649  2.0  0.0  18816  1044 ?        R    16:10   0:00 /usr/sbin/sendmail -i -FCronDaemon -oem www-data
www-data  8654  2.0  0.0  20920  1320 ?        R    16:10   0:00 /usr/sbin/sendmail -i -FCronDaemon -oem www-data
www-data  8664  2.0  0.0   2632   156 ?        R    16:10   0:00 /usr/sbin/postdrop -r
www-data  8673  2.0  0.0  25092  1404 ?        R    16:10   0:00 /usr/sbin/postdrop -r
www-data  8681  2.0  0.0  18696   520 ?        R    16:10   0:00 /usr/sbin/postdrop -r
www-data  8682  0.0  0.0  25096  1468 ?        S    16:10   0:00 /usr/sbin/sendmail -i -FCronDaemon -oem www-data
www-data  8713  1.0  0.0  18704   520 ?        R    16:10   0:00 /usr/sbin/sendmail -i -FCronDaemon -oem www-data
www-data  8720  0.0  0.0  25088  1408 ?        S    16:10   0:00 /usr/sbin/postdrop -r
www-data 19310  0.5  1.6 271260 28300 ?        S    16:05   0:01 php-fpm: pool www                                                       
www-data 22166  0.5  1.7 272196 30404 ?        S    16:05   0:01 php-fpm: pool www                                                       
www-data 22240  0.6  1.1 270468 18880 ?        S    16:05   0:01 php-fpm: pool www
```

When I run `postdrop -d ALL`, after 2 minutes it prints "Killed" on the screen, logs out of the system and forces me to restart the *server*.

Needless to say, I can't send email through any of my websites because, even in the 10 minutes where postfix is running, the email queue is so full nothing can be added to it.

I need help pinpointing the cause of this endless stream of spam.

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you've been hacked. Restore from backups & audit services you're running for missing security patches. http://serverfault.com/ may have better info.

Comment: Seems that user `www-data` is responsible for sending these messages. Your Web server was probably compromised.

Comment: I didn't make any backups. My Web server is Nginx and it serves a few WordPress sites. How can I diagnose which one has the malware?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for posting this as answer, dont have reputation.
If you look at this `from=<www-data@creatroopers.com>` week already told you it is web server that sends out mails.

Are you using wordpress maybe? First thing to do stop postfix and run some malware detection scripts. Try maldet for example.